# eBPF verifier error in reading map value struct with a __u64 element

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I'm trying to use an eBPF map which looks like this:

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, MAX_ENTRIES);
    __type(key, u32);
    __type(value, struct sock_info *);
} lookup SEC(".maps");
```

and sock_info is defined as follows:

```
struct sock_info {
    __u64 ctime;
    __u16 sport;
    __u16 dport;
};
```

When I try to access the value from the map, I am able to read ctime correctly but run into a verifier error accessing sport and dport

```
struct sock_info *og_sock = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&lookup,&pid);

if(og_sock) {
    const char foo[] = "output %llu";
    bpf_trace_printk(foo,sizeof(foo),og_sock->ctime);
}
```

```
10: (b7) r1 = 7695468
; const char foo[] = "output %llu";
11: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -8) = r1
12: (18) r1 = 0x252074757074756f
14: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r1
; bpf_trace_printk(foo,sizeof(foo),og_sock->sport);
15: (69) r3 = *(u16 *)(r0 +8)
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R1_w=inv2675266226404750703 R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmmmmmm fp-16_w=inv2675266226404750703
invalid access to map value, value_size=8 off=8 size=2
R0 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 14 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 1
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
```

When I modify the struct as follows:

```
struct sock_info {
    __u16 sport;
    __u16 dport;
    __u64 ctime;
};
```

I can read the values of sport and dport but ctime breaks

```
; if(og_sock) {
9: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+10
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
10: (b7) r1 = 7695468
; const char foo[] = "output %llu";
11: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -8) = r1
12: (18) r1 = 0x252074757074756f
14: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r1
; bpf_trace_printk(foo,sizeof(foo),og_sock->ctime);
15: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r0 +8)
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R1_w=inv2675266226404750703 R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmmmmmm fp-16_w=inv2675266226404750703
invalid access to map value, value_size=8 off=8 size=8
R0 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 14 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 1
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
```

I looked at [this article](https://hechao.li/2019/06/20/An-Invalid-bpf_context-Access-Bug/) but it seems to be related to bpf_sock_ops which I'm not working with.

Kernel info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-20-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13) aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store object of type `struct sock_info` in your BPF map, then its declaration should be:

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, MAX_ENTRIES);
    __type(key, u32);
    __type(value, struct sock_info);
} lookup SEC(".maps");
```

**Note how the `value` type is not a pointer anymore.** Your C code for the lookup doesn't need to change.

---

The verifier fails in this way because it assumes that you wanted to store pointers into the map. So it allows you to access 64-bits worth of map value since that's the size of a pointer. Any more and it assumes you're doing an out-of-bound access.